# Unable to flash recovery image into the device

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, htc

I am trying to flash recovery image into my HTC Explorer phone.

The issue is i keep getting `waiting for devices` message when issuing `fastboot` command. the CMD is running with administrative rights leaving the only possible reason be the drivers not installed. However i have also done that.

And when i boot my phone normally the device shows totally ok in device manager but when into fastboot mode the device manager shows a yellow mark on the device.

even if i try to install the drivers from there it says drivers already upto date.

Why is this happening and how can i solve this please help?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have USB debugging ticked in developer settings.

If that doesn't work I would uninstall all the drivers relating to your phone and start again from scratch. Note that the drivers that are needed while in fastboot can be different to the drivers needed for normal data transfer. I've had all kinds of problems relating to this a with my HTC One X.